# Как изменить css на сайте через код приложения (работаю в Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone, webview

Здравствуйте всем!

Есть проект на Objective-C. Работаю в Xcode.
Приложение работающее простое просто показывает сайт один в один через WebView.
**Как изменить несколько свойств в css файле сайта через код в приложении?**

Просто хочу несколько блоков убрать через css.
Ну т.е. если чел заходит через приложение они будут не видны, а если через браузер то будут видны.
Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете выполнить java script для содержимого `UIWebView`, лучше всего это сделать, например, в методе `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"<your_code_to_execute_here/>"]
}
```